# What is wrong with realloc?

Tags: c, stack, malloc

I have the following code which you can try using `c99 filename.c; ./a.out`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long int se_t;  // stack element type

se_t stack_size = 0;
se_t *bottom_of_stack = NULL;
#define top_of_stack (bottom_of_stack + stack_size * sizeof(se_t))

#define stack_infix(op) stack_push(stack_pop() #op stack_pop())
#define do_times(x) for(int _i=0; _i<x; _i++)

void stack_push(se_t v) {
    bottom_of_stack = realloc(bottom_of_stack,
                              ++stack_size * sizeof(se_t));
    *top_of_stack = v;
}

void stack_print() {
    printf("stack(%d): \n", (int)stack_size);
    for(se_t *i = bottom_of_stack;
             i <= top_of_stack;
             i += sizeof(se_t)) {
        printf("%p: %d \n", (void*)i, (int)*i);
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 2;
    do_times(3) {
        stack_push(i*=i);
        stack_print();
    }
}
```

I reallocate stack every time I push something to it. Here is the output (with my comments):

```
stack(1): 
0x105200820: 0  // realloc successfully allocated some memory for the first time 
0x105200860: 4 
stack(2): 
0x105200820: 0  // extended the memory range without moving it somewhere else
0x105200860: 4 
0x1052008a0: 16 
stack(3): 
0x105200830: 0  // reallocated the memory to some other region (see the address) 
0x105200870: 0  // and failed for some reason to copy the old data!
0x1052008b0: 0  // why?!
0x1052008f0: 256
```

Comment: It might be worth recommending that `do_times` use the variable `i_##__LINE__` instead of just `i_`. (Personally, I like to do things like `#define CAT_(x, y) x##y` / `#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)` / `#define UNIQ(x) CAT(CAT(INTERNAL_, x), CAT(_DO_NOT_TOUCH_, __LINE__))`)

Comment: Nice idea with `i_##__LINE__`! How did you come up with it? It is almost as `gensym` in Lisp.

Comment: And I guess that `UNIQ(x)` is a 'corporative' version?

Comment: It's a pretty old trick, I forget where I read it first. And `UNIQ` is just being anal. I like having a `UNIQ` macro so that I can easily declare and use local variables in my macros without exposing the mangling scheme to all of them. If I need to change my mangling scheme, I don't have to do find-and-replace across all my macro definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
#define top_of_stack (bottom_of_stack + (stack_size - 1))
```

As it is, you're storing data past the end of the allocated space.

Oh, and change this line too:

```
i += sizeof(se_t)) {
```

Should be:

```
i++) {
```

Because of what `pmg` said about pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Does that means that I don't need `sizeof` in `realloc` as well?

Comment: No, you do need `sizeof` for `realloc`, because `realloc`'s size argument is always in bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer arithmetic already uses `sizeof (basetype)`. When you do

```
#define top_of_stack (bottom_of_stack + stack_size * sizeof(se_t))
```

you are effectively multiplying by `sizeof (se_t)` twice.

if `bottom_of_stack` has the value `0xF000` and `stack_size` is 2 and `sizeof (se_t)` is 0x10

```
bottom_of_stack + stack_size == 0xF020
bottom_of_stack + stack_size * sizeof (se_t) == 0xF400 /* or whatever */
```